# Karma is not seeing test files

Tags: javascript, jasmine, requirejs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I used to use my SpecRunner.html to run Jasmine tests but I'd like to change it for Karma testrunner. However, I have problems with configuration of Karma + requirejs.

This is my working tree:

[image]

This is my SpecRunner.html file now (working right):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.6.4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
        <script src="../../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script src="../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script src="../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
        <script src="../../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
        <script src="../../libs/js/10-jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<script>
    require({
        baseURL: '../',
        paths: {
            spec: 'test',
            src: '../src/',
            jquery: '../../libs/js/10-jquery-2.1.1.js'
        }
    }, ['test', 'custom-test', 'src/custom', 'jquery'], function () {
        jasmine.getEnv().execute();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Karma config file:

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [{
    pattern: 'libs/**/*.js',
    included: true
  },
  {
    pattern: 'angular/core/**/*.js',
    included: true
  },
  {
    pattern: 'angular/app.js',
    included: true
  },
  {
    pattern: 'angular/*.js',
    included: true
  },
  {
    pattern: 'js/src/*.js',
    included: true
  },
  {
    pattern: 'js/test/*.js',
    included: true
  }
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher
browsers: [
  'PhantomJS',
  // 'Chrome', 
  // 'Firefox', 
  // 'FirefoxDeveloper', 
  // 'IE'
],

plugins: [
  'karma-requirejs',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-firefox-launcher',
  'karma-ie-launcher',
  'karma-coverage'
],

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

And require.js config in the main-test.js file:

```
require.config({
baseURL: '../',
paths: {
    spec: 'test',
    src: '../src/',
    jquery: '../../libs/js/10-jquery-2.1.1.js'
}
}, ['test', 'custom-test', 'src/custom', 'jquery'], function () {
jasmine.getEnv().execute();
});
```

When I run Karma now I get this message:

> 23 06 2017 14:50:13.862:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]:
> Connected on socket y4PBKhfyD7iwuxmlAAAA with id 40738505 PhantomJS
> 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR   Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {return e;}
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch   at
> node_modules/requirejs/require.js:143

I have no idea what can I change to make it right, I tried various attitudes for a few hours, using Karma and RequireJS documentation but it's still not working.